# Is a pointer to a STL container safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

What if I make a `unique_ptr` point to an instance of an STL container as follows? Is this code safe?

```
unique_ptr< vector<int> > p1( new vector<int> );
```

Wouldn't this result in the destructor for the `vector<int>` being called twice, since both the `vector<int>` itself and the `unique_ptr` both attempt to clean up the memory the `vector<int>` had acquired so far? Could this result in undefined behavior?  Or does the compiler somehow knows that that `vector<int>` has released its memory and does not invoke the destructor again for the sake of the `unique_ptr` going out of scope?

This is simply to understand that if someone was stupid enough to do this, could it be dangerous?

Comment: There's nothing unsafe about your code, but it is very unlikely you actually need `unique_ptr<vector<int>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `unique_ptr< vector<int> > p1( new vector<int> );` the `unique_ptr` with call `delete` on the `vector`.
The destructor of `vector` will then release its own allocated memory.
So it is safe.

But `vector<int>` is enough. I don't see a case where you'd want `unique_ptr< vector<int> >`.

Comment: But wouldn't this result into two calls to the `delete` of the vector?

Comment: @FirstJens Where would the second call come from?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, it calls the destructor, and when the `vector<int>` goes out of scope, it again calls its own destructor. No?

Comment: @FirstJens The `vector` never goes out of scope because it is allocated on the free store. That's why you have to `delete` it explicitly or, preferably, have the `unique_ptr` do that job for you.

Comment: @FirstJens Only the `unique_ptr` will go out of scope. You allocate the vector with new, it's not a stack based variable that would be deleted automatically.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So, if I was using a raw pointer to point to a `vector<int>`, would it then leak memory if I forgot to call `delete` on the raw pointer?

Comment: @FirstJens Yes, it would

Comment: @FirstJens: Whether there is a raw pointer pointing at it or not is irrelevant. What matters is whether you allocated it with `new`.

Comment: When you allocate something with `new`, the thing you allocated has no scope and so can never go out of scope. The naked pointer that `new` returns does go out of scope, but naked pointers don't do anything when destructed.

Comment: What David says is true, but to appreciate it fully you need to understand the difference between scope (which is something variables have, or to be really precise it's something names have) and lifetime (which is something objects have). The object of type `vector<int>` that was allocated with `new` is not a variable and that is why it has no scope.